# Firewall/Port requirements for Helm 2.16

Tags: kubernetes-helm

We are installing helmv2.16 on Kubernetes v1.14 in offline mode.We downloaded the tiller docker image and loaded on the server where we were installing the helm

i.  No access to Internet from the application servers
ii. Limited ports connectivity between the Kubernetes master and worker nodes(No * connectivity between the servers). The ports that are opened between the application servers are -
a.10250-10260
b.6443
c.443
d.2379-2380
e.Node port series 30000-32767
f. 44134-44135

We downloaded the Helm 2.16 and installed following the below steps. The tiller pod failed to come up till we allowed ALL communication between kubernetes master and kubernetes worker nodes. This means that there are specific firewall requirements for Helm/tiller to function in a kubernetes cluster. Could someone please share the port / firewall details since we do not want to open ALL traffic even between the nodes of a cluster (rather we would open specific ports).

kubectl create serviceaccount --namespace kube-system tiller
kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller-cluster-rule --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:tiller
helm init   --service-account tiller --skip-refresh